# Set sql parameter value in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
SELECT g.date,g.description,g.amount AS cash,0 AS cheque FROM generalledger AS g WHERE g.type="cash" AND (g.date=@gdate OR @gdate IS NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT gg.date,gg.description,0 AS cash, gg.amount AS cheque FROM generalledger AS gg WHERE gg.type="cheque" AND (gg.date=@gdate OR @gdate IS NULL)
```

I've this query I want to set the @gdate parameter value from php function, I'm using codeigniter. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Bindings enable you to simplify your query syntax by letting the system put the queries together for you. Consider the following example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";

$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
```

The question marks in the query are automatically replaced with the values in the array in the second parameter of the query function.

Comment: I'm not looking for this, I've some sql variable like this
SET @gdate := NULL;

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
SELECT g.date,g.description,g.amount AS cash,0 AS cheque 
FROM generalledger AS g, (SELECT @gdate := NULL) as a
WHERE g.type="cash" AND (g.date=@gdate OR @gdate IS NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT gg.date,gg.description,0 AS cash, gg.amount AS cheque 
FROM generalledger AS gg, (SELECT @gdate := NULL) as b
WHERE gg.type="cheque" AND (gg.date=@gadte OR @gdate IS NULL)
```